# Anylogic: Is there an alternative to the delay block in order to stop an agent over a path until a given simulation time is reached?

Tags: anylogic

If someone wants to delay an agent over the path, the delay block can be used customizing the delay time in order to get a deterministic exit time matching the desired simulation time.
Exists an alternative to that?

Comment: What do you aim to achieve? Why is the delay block not enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wait block with an event inside the agent that is going to be triggered after your delay time is over and call the free() function to get out of the wait block.

Nevertheless, you can customize your delay time in the delay block by using agent.delay (assuming that you have a variable called delay in your agent that identifies how long the delay will be for the agent)